# displaying the lightning data in CSV file proper format

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datatable, table

i am downloading the lightning data in CSV file as per the below screenshot
[image]

Now the issue is whenever i am trying to expand the **Name** column,the data is getting restricted to the name column only.Like the industry field value 'engineering','Consulting' is not getting shifted to the industry column.
**The reason being the data is concatenated and then coming in CSV as per the below code.**

```
for(var key in dat.getReturnValue()){
  csvContent +=dat.getReturnValue()[key].Name+" "+dat.getReturnValue()[key].Industry+"\r\n" ;
  }

            var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
```

Comment: where exactly are you stuck? what problem are you facing? any errors? what is the current behavior, vs the expected one?

Comment: actually the values in rows needs to be displayed exactly in CSV file after download,so the format is just like i have asked . in my code only name is coming ,don't know how to fetch industry and phone field.

Comment: @glls :- have edited the js controller code for table header.But how to align the records under the heading .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In for loop you can make changes as below code:

```
for (var key in response.getReturnValue()) {
    rows.push(response.getReturnValue()[key].Name + "," + response.getReturnValue()[key].City + "," + response.getReturnValue()[key].Phone);
}
const rowsHeader = [
    ["Name", "City", "Phone"]

];

 let str = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    rowsHeader.forEach(function(header) {
    // Here it will get all the values with comma separated.
        str += header + "\r\n";
  });
```

Hope it will solve your question!

Comment: i think almost i got it but some garbage values are coming. let me try it once more.

Comment: Can you post what garbage values you are getting in CSV file?

Comment: the third column 'undefined' is coming on its own. i have used ur code for the first two columns only .Dont know from where the third column undefined is coming.

Comment: can you edit your post with latest code?

Comment: is it possible to modify the code in such a way ,that the record section should also get movable.???

Comment: Can you edit your post with latest code? Then we will take into enhancement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98994/discussion-between-chetan-nandre-and-vineet).

Comment: You missed comma inside for loop concating string. In CSV, comma is used for separating values

Comment: @ Chetan finally your code made my day.Cant believe it was just comma.